# create date in python without time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to get the current date without time and then compare that date with other entered by user

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Example

```
currentDate="01/08/2015"
userDate="01/07/2015"
if currentData > userDate:
 .........
else:
  ...................
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `datetime.date` objects , they do not have a time part.

You can get current date using `datetime.date.today()` , Example -

```
now = datetime.date.today()
```

This would give you an object of type - `datetime.date` . And you can get the `date()` part of a `datetime` object , by using the `.date()` method , and then you can compare both dates.

Example -

```
now = datetime.date.today()
currentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

Then you can compare them.

Also, to convert the string to a date , you should use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) as I have used above , example -

```
currentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

This would cause, `currentDate` to be a `datetime.date` object.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> now = datetime.date.today()
>>> currentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y').date()
>>> now > currentDate
False
>>> now < currentDate
False
>>> now == currentDate
True
```

Comment: thanks. My best  problem is how  I convert an objeto string "12/02/2010" to date

Comment: Use `strptime` , Added tht to my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for my in Python 3.9.5:  

`>>> datetime.date.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'now'`  

`datetime.date` is a method, not an object.   The following works:  
`datetime.date(datetime.now())`

Comment: (sorry, couldn't figure out how to get the formatting right with line breaks...)

Comment: @mropp, `datetime.date` does not have a `now` attribute. That's exactly what Python is telling you. `datetime.datetime` has the `now` method, you want to use `today`: `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: @neilg Thanks.  Yeah, the original answer (which has now been edited) was saying to use `datetime.date.now(()` which is why I mentioned that didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3.9.5:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.min)
```

Which gives the result (if run on December 9, 2021):

```
datetime.date(2021, 12, 9)
```

which is a datetime object.

As [Anand S. Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795990/anand-s-kumar)'s reply states, you should use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert the user provided date to a datetime object as well. Then you can do simple comparison for equality (`==`), `>`, `<`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:
datetime.today().date()

Result:
datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)

Comment: 1) your answer is wrong; 2) the correct answer was given on Aug 1 '15 at 4:51

Comment: i don't understand. I had a similar problem, and It works for me.

Comment: It doesn't work: module datetime does not have method today(). However, datetime module has a built-in object called datetime, in order for your solution to work you need an import statement: from datetime import datetime

Comment: ah. that's true. sorry

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`

# get today date
`print(datetime.today().date())`
2021, 6, 2

Comment: Please just delete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you looking for the answer in 2023, try:

```
datetime.date(datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare dates, then compare dates, not strings. Use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to parse the user's entered date.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
userDate = "01/07/2015"
if datetime.datetime.strptime(userDate, '%m/%d/%Y') < now:
    ...
```